# Find and go to last row in column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following sheet. Rows are not a fixed number and can vary.

[image]

I want to select one cell below the last row in column B. It will always be column B, but sometimes there are more rows.

[image]

I am just starting off with VBA and macros, so not much effort from my side to show, apologies.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim Rng As Long
Rng = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(Rng, 2).Select
```

The variable Rng contains always the row number of the last cell in B plus one row.